# Composition Api is not work in node_modules when i used in my vue2.7 project created by @vue/cli

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli, vue-composition-api

Environment info

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfPpY.png)

```
// vue.config.js
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true
})
```

Steps to reproduce

1. create vue2.7 components lib；
2. use Composition API like `const num = ref(0)`;
3. yarn link;
4. ’my-vue2.7-project‘ yarn link lib；
   5.ref doesn't work

What is expected?

Composition Api works in node_modules

Comment: Two questions to clarify: 1. Are there any error by building/running? 2.  What exactly does mean "ref doesn't work"?. Please, show the code. Since you noticed the `node_modules`, how do you try to use the `Composition API`. Do you try to use it in the backend functions?

Comment: Check also [Migration to Vue 2.7](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration-vue-2-7.html) if there is something you have missed.